# Problems with VS Code anda packaging naming in java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

I have created a new Java project in Vs Code. Inside the src folder I have created the folder structure for the project like this:

```
ProjectFolder
    |_ src
        |_ com
            |_ dname
               |_ projectname
                   |_ model
                   |   |_ Model.java
                   |
                   |_ view
                   |   |_ View.java
                   |
                   |_ controller
                   |   |_ Controller.java
                   |
                   |_ ProjectName.java
```

On each of the java classes  I have added the package name to the top of the file:

- Model.java:        `package model;`
- View.java:         `package view;`
- Controller.java:   `package controller;`

Then I import this packages in `ProjectName.java`like this:

```
import com.dname.projectname.model.Model; 
import com.dname.projectname.view.View; 
import com.dname.projectname.controller.Controller;
```

The problem is that during compilation I get the following error:

```
The import com cannot be resolved
```

How can I solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package name needs to be `com.dname.projectname.model` and not `package model`.